# django countries currency code

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-1.5, django-countries

I am using `django_countries` to show the countries list. Now, I have a requirement where I need to show currency according to country. 
Norway - NOK, Europe & Afrika (besides UK) - EUR, UK - GBP, AMERICAS & ASIA - USDs.

Could this be achieved through django_countries project? or are there any other packages in python or django which I could use for this?

Any other solution is welcomed as well.

--------------------------- UPDATE -------------
The main emphasis is on this after getting lot of solutions:
`Norway - NOK, Europe & Afrika (besides UK) - EUR, UK - GBP, AMERICAS & ASIA - USDs.`

---------------------------- SOLUTION --------------------------------

My solution was quite simple, when I realized that I couldnt get any ISO format or a package to get what I want, I thought to write my own script. It is just a conditional based logic:

```
from incf.countryutils import transformations
def getCurrencyCode(self, countryCode):
        continent = transformations.cca_to_ctn(countryCode)
        # print continent
        if str(countryCode) == 'NO':
            return 'NOK'

        if str(countryCode) == 'GB':
            return 'GBP'

        if (continent == 'Europe') or (continent == 'Africa'):
            return 'EUR'

        return 'USD'
```

Dont know whether this is efficient way or not, would like to hear some suggestions.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several modules out there:

- [pycountry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry):

  ```
  import pycountry

  country = pycountry.countries.get(name='Norway')
  currency = pycountry.currencies.get(numeric=country.numeric)

  print currency.alpha_3
  print currency.name
  ```

  prints:

  ```
  NOK 
  Norwegian Krone
  ```
- [py-moneyed](https://github.com/limist/py-moneyed)

  ```
  import moneyed

  country_name = 'France'

  for currency, data in moneyed.CURRENCIES.iteritems():
      if country_name.upper() in data.countries:
          print currency
          break
  ```

  prints `EUR`
- [python-money](https://github.com/poswald/python-money)

  ```
  import money

  country_name = 'France'

  for currency, data in money.CURRENCY.iteritems():
      if country_name.upper() in data.countries:
          print currency
          break
  ```

  prints `EUR`

`pycountry` is regularly updated, `py-moneyed` looks great and has more features than `python-money`, plus `python-money` is not maintained now.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, looks promising, but would that give me currency code according to group as well? Like Europe and Afrika (besides UK) it should be EUR and so on?

Comment: You are welcome. Mm, I don't think there is one particular module you need. `pycountry` operates on country (and country subdivisions too) level.

Comment: Well..here is the thing, I tried your code, it works fine with Norway..but when I replaced it with France, it gave me an error: `u'250'` `site-packages\pycountry\db.py in get, line 87`. In any case it doesnt work like the way I expected, as I tried it with India now, but instead of USD its giving INR.

Comment: Yeah, this is because France has no country-specific currency. `French Franc` was withdrawn in 2002. FYI, `pycountry` uses [ISO 4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) standard for currencies..

Comment: How to define that the currency for France is `EUR` - this is a good and open question.

Comment: @mad_programmer I've added 2 more options, please check.

Comment: I have checked it, it works for few cases but not for others, like if I write any country in Africa, lets say 'Congo', it doesnt print anything. I guess, I need a custom script to do this.

Comment: Sure, take a look at online services for getting currencies, e.g. http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx.

Comment: Ok, is there any package which gives me the continent name back when given the country name or country code?

Comment: Thanks so much..I think I could use that to write a conditional code snippet and assign the currency :)

Comment: @mad_programmer great! Consider posting your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

`django-countries` just hands you a field to couple to your model (and a static bundle with flag icons). The field can hold a 2 character ISO from the list in `countries.py` which is convenient if this list is up-to-date (haven't checked) because it saves a lot of typing.

If you wish to create a model with verbose data that's easily achieved, e.g.

```
class Country(models.Model):
    iso = CountryField()
    currency = # m2m, fk, char or int field with pre-defined 
               # choices or whatever suits you

>> obj = Country.objects.create(iso='NZ', currency='NZD')
>> obj.iso.code
u'NZ'
>> obj.get_iso_display()
u'New Zealand'
>> obj.currency
u'NZD'
```

An example script of preloading data, which could later be exported to create a fixture which is a nicer way of managing sample data.

```
from django_countries.countries import COUNTRIES

for key in dict(COUNTRIES).keys():
    Country.objects.create(iso=key)
```

Comment: I dont want to create it. If that is the case then I have to create a long list.

Comment: You could easily write a script that creates the fixtures for you, it wouldn't take more then 2 minutes.

Comment: And that is precisely what I am not able to understand how? :)

Answer (score 3):

I have just released [country-currencies](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/country-currencies), a module that gives you a mapping of country codes to currencies.

```
>>> from country_currencies import get_by_country
>>> get_by_country('US')
('USD',)
>>> get_by_country('ZW')
('USD', 'ZAR', 'BWP', 'GBP', 'EUR')
```